# Time-Space aquarium with paths

Tags: qgis, path, space-time-cube

I am trying to reproduce this kind of spatial representation with QGIS. It's a space-time aquarium where each line represents a path compared to time:
[image]

It is a representation from the *Time geography*, in theory with this scheme :
[image]

I have no idea how to produce this map. I already have my paths on QGIS with schedules (example : "home" 0:00 am to 7:00 am, "work" 8:00 am to 5:00 pm, etc.).

Does anyone have an idea on QGIS ?

EDIT :

I have created my line with one z-value (z= 150 here). I just would like to set : start at X z-value and end at X z-value. Is it possible with a line ? I am a beginner on QGIS...

[image]

EDIT 2 :

I tried to build my line from two points (with a z-value). But I don't know how to specify to begin at one z-value and end to another. Any idea ?
[image]

Comment: You may try to create a polyline where you encode the time as the z value of each vertice and use the 3d capability of qgis to display it.

Comment: Reminds me of space-time-cube. Not (yet?) implemented in QGIS, but tehre might be workarounds as the one proposed by @J.R

Comment: Space-time cube is not implemented in QGIS, but I try to find a way with the 2threejs plugin (3D).

Comment: I don't know how to encode le z value of the vertices of my line.

Comment: If you have your points with z value then you just need to use a tool that make line from point ( not sure of the exact name of the tool but it should be easy to find)

Comment: Building on @JR comment. You could try using LINESTRING M from Well Known Text format. You could structure that in excel using CONCATENATE to build the WKT and then save as CSV. Open that file in QGIS checking the WKT box.